# How to model predicted proportion data without weights

Tags: generalized-linear-model, proportion, glmmtmb

**Research Question**

I am trying to determine if maternal nest-site choice influences offspring sex ratio in a species where nest temperature determines sex.

**Data**

I have temperature traces from real nest sites and random sites at six nesting locations. The data was collected over five years. From these temperature traces, I have calculated a predicted sex ratio for each nest and random site. The sex ratio data is continuous, bounded by 0 and 1, with a large number of zeros and ones. Here is a histogram of the data:
[image: Histogram of sex ratio data]

I'd like to know if sex ratios vary between nests and random sites, and if this relationship varies between locations.

**Analysis Options**

Normally, when analysing sex ratio data, I would use a glmm with the binomial or betabinomial error distribution and the number of sexed individuals as the weight term. However, I can't do that in this case because the sex ratios are predicted values, not associated with any real individuals. I have considered three options to solve this issue.

1. Use my predicted sex ratios to generate a number of "fake" individuals for each nest/random site and then use that number as the weights for a binomial/betabinomial glmm. This seems a little too hacky.
2. Use a zero-one inflated beta model (ZOIB). Based on my reading, ZOIB models are appropriate when zero or one values originate from a different underlying process than intermediate values (sources:1,2,3). I don't think this is the case with my data (the difference between a sex ratio of 0 and 0.1 is biologically the same as the difference between a sex ratio of 0.1 and 0.2), although maybe the fact that there are a wider range of temperatures that produce 0 or 1 sex ratios means these results should be treated differently to intermediate values.
3. Use ordered beta regression. Robert Kubenic's method for analysing continuous proportions seems like it might be appropriate for my data (source: 2). I trialed it using the "ordbeta" family in glmmTMB (the model was: Sex Ratio ~ Location*SiteType + (1|year), family=ordbeta), however I don't think the error distribution of my data matches the ordbeta error distribution. My residual plots (made in DHARMa) suggest that the residual error isn't uniform.
   [image: sex ratio model residual and qqplot]

Further inspection suggests that there is variation in residual error between the locations:
[image: residual plot for categorical predictor: location]

I used performance::check_predictions to compare model predicted and real values. It seems like there is greater prediction error around zero and one than intermediate values.
[image: model predictions compared to data]

I'm wondering if ordered beta regression is the best approach to analysing my data, or if I should try a different solution? If ordered beta regression is the right way to go, what should I do about the error variance issues?

-Thanks

Sources:

1. https://www.theanalysisfactor.com/zero-one-inflated-beta-models-for-proportion-data/
2. https://www.robertkubinec.com/post/limited_dvs/
3. https://twitter.com/bolkerb/status/1577755600808775680

Comment: Could you explain the sense in which a sex ratio -- which sounds like one count divided by another -- should be considered "continuous"?  What are you counting, what is this a ratio of, and what are typical values of those counts?  Since you describe this as "predicted," then in what sense does that help you assess its relationship with temperature?

Comment: Are you only comparing the model predicted sex ratio between actual nesting sites and randomly selected sites, or are you comparing observed sex ratios of baby birds born in those nests to the model predicted sex ratios?

Comment: @whuber My data is an expected sex ratio rather than a real sex ratio. I used an equation that describes the relationship between sex and temperature for our study species and predicted the chance of developing as a male at the recorded temperatures (0 = no chance to be male, 1= 100% chance of being male). Any value between 0 and 1 is possible, so I don't think I can model it as a discrete varaible, though I should have described it as a probability, not a ratio, sorry! With real sex data you would divide the number of males by the number of females to get the sex ratio.

Comment: @whuber I'm not actually looking at the relationship between sex and temperature. I'm testing whether the maternally selected sites would produce different sex ratios than the random sites.

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica, I'm only comparing the model predicted sex ratios, as we don't have true sex ratio data for many of the nests (for turtles juvenile sex can't be determined without euthanizing hatchlings).

Comment: I'm guessing `siteType` is actual nest vs random spot.  What then is `location`?  Do you have observations at matched times?  If the model predicted sex ratios are just based on temperatures, can you eschew the whole thing and just compare the temperatures of the actual nests vs random spots?

Comment: Ah, turtles!  I read "nests" and assumed *birds*.  Lol.

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica, location is the different river banks that we recorded nesting. They are distributed over a wide geographic range, and experience different climates, so we expect that sex ratios may vary between the locations.

Comment: Sure.  Can you just compare the temperatures?  Are the observations of the actual nests and random spots paired?

Comment: I could compare temperatures (which would certainly be more simple), but there are potential differences in temperature that would not result in differences in sex ratio (e.g cold and very cold nests are still 100% male). Random nests tend to be more extreme temps, so I'm worried that just comparing temps wouldn't answer the question of if maternal nesting behaviour influences sex ratio.

Comment: Huh, interesting.  Is it the variances of the temperatures that matters and not the means?  (Be sure to "@" me to ensure that I am aware of your response.)  It is possible to compare variances.  Also, are the sex ratios predicted directly, or are they based on, say, predicted probabilities or predicted odds, etc?  Would you have those?  If they were, say, probabilities, are they actually exact 0's, eg, or would it be something like .0000001, where realistically you would get all one sex?

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica, after considering it over the weekend, I think your suggestion to analyse the temp data rather than predicted SRs is probably the way forward. I was concerned that I would find a statistically significant difference between the sites, that wouldn't relate to a biological difference in SRs. However, I can use the parameter estimates of a temp ~ location*site_type model to see what SRs the different categories would produce and decide if there are biologically relevant differences between the sites.

Comment: That sounds good.  Let me know if you are interested in the variability of the temps (higher highs and lower lows) instead of the mean temps.  Otherwise, I might just condense these comments into an 'answer' to give this thread some closure.

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica, I am interested if you have time to elaborate. Thanks very much for your help so far.

Answer (score 2):

Those plots are not valid for the ordered beta distribution, which is a mixture of discrete and continuous responses. To get a better view of fit, use the pp_check_ordbeta function in the ordbetareg package (see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ordbetareg/vignettes/package_introduction.html). However, in any case I wouldn't say that any of those plots show substantial misfit. For a distribution to be useful, it doesn't need (nor do you necessarily want) to incorporate all the features of your data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Do you think it's appropriate to model this data with an ordered beta regression? I am considering using the underlying temperature data instead.

Comment: Absolutely, that’s the exact sort of distribution I wrote the model for. Use the marginaleffects package with ordbetareg and you’ll get easy to interpret covariate effects. See the package vignette for info.